# Are there any spirits dealing with oaths in world of darkness

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, werewolf-the-apocalypse, spirits, umbra

I want the spirit to function as a kolyarut  to enforce a contract since I don't have entropy 5 there is always homebrew but I want to know if one already exists

Answer (score 6):

It may not have the exact details you want, but there is an option suggested by *Vampire: the Masquerade*. The level 5 Thaumaturgy ritual *Blood Contract* has an effect like you describe, and implies that demons can be associated with compliance:

> **Blood Contract**
>
> This ritual creates an unbreakable agreement between
> the two parties who sign it. The contract must
> be written in the caster’s blood and signed in the blood
> of whoever applies their name to the document. This
> ritual takes three nights to enact fully, after which both
> parties are compelled to fulfill the terms of the contract.
>
> System: This ritual is best handled by the Storyteller,
> who may bring those who sign the blood contract
> into compliance by whatever means necessary (it is
> not unknown for demons to materialize and enforce
> adherence to certain blood contracts). [...] (*V20* Core Rulebook, page 239)

The details are left undefined, but that the ritual describes demons appearing to enforce contracts sometimes (meaning not *all* the time) indicates that the magic surrounding the contracts themselves is not necessarily enough to ensure compliance. This in turn suggests that at least some demons have some association with keeping or enforcing contracts, at least in some cases. It's not much of a stretch to go from a contract to an oath.

This doesn't answer how a character would go about contacting or getting such a creature to enforce a contract (outside of this particular ritual, which will not be directly available to a mage), but it is at least an option with some representation in the published books.